# Layout of 2 RecyclerViews tip

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create the ui depicted in the design below. Basically it will be an horizontal RecyclerView and below that a vertical one. What I want is that when i scroll vertically, the horizontal one should move too instead of only scrolling the vertical one.

[image]
Now I thought of putting the horizontal one in the first cell of the vertical with a different viewholder, but isn't that a bit expensive performance-wise (as i would have to reinitialize and populate the horizontal one after the cell gets recycled and bind() is called)?

So I am asking is there any better approach? Or should I go on with this one?
For the record: minimum API: 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the 2 `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` here [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok will try! I am really interested in smooth scrolling! So if it is good i will accept you!